# Excell Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 Using "x"

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to pull information from "sheet 1" in excell to "sheet 2". I have a listing of equipment on sheet one and when I put an "x" in column "A" next to that equipment, I would like it to pull all that specific information over to "sheet 2". Can someone help me with the formula I need to use?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the combination of IF and VLOOKUP. IF to check that the column has an x and VLOOKUP to find the value from the other sheet.

I can strongly recommend you the Excel Basic section on [chandoo.org](http://chandoo.org/wp/excel-basics/)

DavidPostill has right anyway...at last yo have to try...

And not Excell but Excel...with 1 "l".

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for trying to help on this question.  The site is a knowledgebase, so answers are intended to be solutions to the question.  Providing helpful hints and pointing the questioner in the right direction should be done in a comment, which requires a little more rep.  Answers that should be comments tend to attract downvotes, which will detract from accumulating the rep to comment, vote, etc.